# InfoPath Form Reset Main Data Connection

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint, infopath

I'm building an InfoPath form connected to a SharePoint List.

After the user has filled out a couple of fields (which can uniquely identify a record), I re-query the main data connection to see if the item already exists. This works fine and loads the remaining details of the existing record into the form.

However, if the record does not exist, all the fields on the form become disabled... how can I reset the main data connection back to its initial state to allow a new item to be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a condition rule. So for example on the last field the do an insert on do your query, then in your rules (you may need multiple depending on how many fields) , saying if field is (whatever) then do (whatever). The disable features are set in the formatting section of your rule.